# ASP.NET MVC2 call a service method from the master page?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

In my MVC2 app that uses the Service - Repository pattern, how can I call a service method from the master page?

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Logo                      Welcome xyz|
+--------------------------------------+
| Home | Sales | Import | Admin (menu) |
+--------------------------------------+
```

In my menu I now have some pages that have restricted access by user role.  I have an existing service method that can check if the current user can view a certain page or not:

```
IPageAccessService.CanAccess(int pageId, int roleId);
```

On the controller methods I can call this to check if the user can see the page or not:

```
public ActionResult Update(int id?)
{
    if (!_pageAccessService.CanAccess(pageId, roleId))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to call this method from my Site.Master so that when it creates the menu it does not show the menu item if the user does not have access (the menu is a simple unordered list):

```
<li><a href="<%=Url.Content("~/Admin") %>">Admin</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="<%=Url.Content("~/Admin/Roles") %>">User Roles</a></li>
    <li><a href="<%=Url.Content("~/Admin/AdminReports") %>">Admin Reports</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I'm guessing that it would need look something like this (have to check each page before adding to the list):

```
if (_pageAccessService.CanAccess(pageId, roleId)) <li><a href="<%=Url.Content("~/Admin") %>">Admin</a>
<ul>
        if (_pageAccessService.CanAccess(pageId, roleId)) <li><a href="<%=Url.Content("~/Admin/Roles") %>">User Roles</a></li>
        if (_pageAccessService.CanAccess(pageId, roleId)) <li><a href="<%=Url.Content("~/Admin/AdminReports") %>">Admin Reports</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

But before I can do that I need to know how to actually call a service method from the master.

EDIT:

I've adapted Darin's answer and have this:

```
public static class LinkExtensions
{
    private static readonly IPageAccessRepository _repo = new PageAccessRepository();
    private static readonly IPageAccessService _pageAccess = new PageAccessService(_repo);

    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText,
    string url, string pageName
    )
    {
        if (!_pageAccess.CanAccess(pageName))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        // The user can access the page => show the menu
        var a = new TagBuilder("a");
        a.Attributes["href"] = url;
        a.SetInnerText(linkText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<li>{0}</li>",a));
    }
```

The problem is that I still need to call the service, so I need to be able to instantiate it.  Because its a static class, my IoC container won't help here.  So I still have to manually do create the service and repository. And it's still got the same problem as my original ugly workaround - manually creating a repository in a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom HTML helper rendering the different items of this menu. Inside the helper based on the user roles you will decide whether to generate or not the given item. For example something among the lines:

```
public static class LinkExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string linkText,
        string url,
        string requiredRole
    )
    {
        var a = new TagBuilder("a");
        a.Attributes["href"] = url;
        a.SetInnerText(linkText);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requiredRole))
        {
            // No role required => show the menu item
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(a.ToString());
        }

        var user = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (!user.IsInRole(requiredRole))
        {
            // A role is required but no user authenticated or user is not in role
            // => show empty
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        // The user is in role => show the menu
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

and inside the view:

```
<li>
    <%= Html.MenuItem("Admin", Url.Content("~/Admin"), "admin") %>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <%= Html.MenuItem("User Roles", Url.Content("~/Admin/Roles"), "userroles") %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <%= Html.MenuItem("Admin Reports", Url.Content("~/Admin/AdminReports"), "admin") %>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Another possibility is to use child actions and the [Html.Action helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) inside the master.

Comment: Wont this lead to a bunch of empty `<li>` tags? Not sure what that will do to the menu.  I just tried manually adding an empty `<li>` and it didn't break the menu so that's good.

Comment: @JK, yes it will. You could include them inside the helper just before returning: `return MvcHtmlString.Create("<li>" + a.ToString() + "</li>");`.

Comment: thanks, that came pretty close. But I still need to call the IPageAccessService.CanAccess() method. Because the extension is static I cant use IoC and still have to manually create a Repository (question updated to show this)

Answer (score 1):

Anything that requires logic should not be in Views, including their helpers of course.

I'd suggest for this you add a new Controller Action, add your logic to the action, and return the username directly from the controller or if you want to display more stuff like login controls whatever you can use a view.

So, create `LoginWelcomeMessage` class with `Username` and `IsLoggedIn` properties for example. In the action set those based on the whatever checks you want, and send them to the view which shows/hides based on them.

In your masterpage, you execute `@Html.RenderAction()` to execute the action that brings the username and so on.

The same idea can be done for the entire menu. IT's up to you whether to have the whole header in one Action / View or have two different ones. If you have the same view then the model can have extra properties like `CanViewSalesMenuItems`, `CanViewAdminMenuItems` and so on, that are set from your action method, and used from its view to display/hide items.

The beauty is that the masterpage won't care, it just delegates the whole thing to the controller action and its view using `RenderAction()`

Comment: yes I agree it cant be right to instantiate the service/repo in the view (and extension is for all intents part of the view). I already managed to switch the menu to a controller action which is called from site.master using Html.Action (its MVC2). But I didn't quite follow what you said about extra properties used in the view to hide/display the items.

Comment: I was talking about the view of the action you added. Normally you'll create a special class (usually called ViewModel, regardless of the actual naming of the class). This class should have UI-specific features (like "Show"/"Hide"/...). The controller calls the business services and based on that assign the properties in ViewModel, then sends it to the View, which uses them for rendering itself.